# Why does the dock appear on the left when my screen is locked?

Tags: gnome-shell, lock-screen, gnome-shell-extension, ubuntu-dock, 18.10

The dock doesn't work correctly after I enter my password, either.

[image: photo of lock screen with dock]

Comment: @pomsky Here are the extensions that I have installed: `Float MPV`, `Gsconnect`, `appindicator support`, `Ubuntu Dock`, the last 2 are pre-installed on the system.

Comment: I didn't have this issue until I installed the ubuntu dock extension w/ osx-style app dock (extension linked from gnome-tweaks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was [reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1769383) as being fixed in the package gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock, 0.9.1ubuntu18.04.3. Perhaps the bug will go away if you update to that package.

Comment: Yes, it has been fixed.

Comment: I'm still facing this issue in the lastest ubuntu 20.04 version.

Answer (score 4):

This should not happen under normal circumstances, as per GNOME's security policy, whenever you enter the lock screen all the extensions get disabled automatically until you get back in, and then the extensions get re-enabled. Somehow it's failing here for the Ubuntu Dock extension (`gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`) and so it's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1769383).

**Note:** Bug reports are off-topic here.

As a temporary workaround either restart (or relogin to) your system or restart GNOME shell by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>, then typing `r` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I hope that they will fix it soon.

Comment: Oh! My! God! The bug has been reported since May.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved with the following command, found it on this github issue: https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/649#issuecomment-348433909

```
$ sudo mv /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com ~/
```

*NOTE the comments below about how this is hacky and a very undesirable method to solve the issue.*

Comment: This will just forcefully move the system folder for Ubuntu Dock to your home directory. This is highly *not* recommended. Moving or editing or deleting system files blindly with `sudo` is not recommended in general and also the package for Ubuntu Dock is a system package, `ubuntu-desktop` metapacakge depends on it. So update to any associated package or metapackage will most certainly bring that directory back.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution, I had the same problem in ubuntu 19.10 (sic!).
And this command fixed it:
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock transparency-mode FIXED

Comment: can you explain a little how works your command? If you can't, where did you find it?